# "Faire boomerang / Avoir un effet boomerang", en parlant d'une action hostile qui se retourne contre son auteur : est-ce courant ?

Tags: anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, locutions

Peut-on utiliser couramment la locution

> ["Faire boomerang / avoir un effet boomerang](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/boomerang/10195#locution)" en parlant d'une action hostile, se retourner contre son auteur.

?

Comme par exemple :

> La reforme des mathématiques aura un effet boomerang à notre travail comme professeurs.

Comment: Cette phrase me parait incorrecte. Je dirais plutôt "Le reforme aura un effet négatif/un impact négatif/des conséquences négatives sur les connaissances mathématiques de nos élèves."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Effet boomerang* est une locution courante, *faire boomerang* beaucoup moins.

On parle d'effet boomerang quand on fait quelque chose de précis à destination de personnes ou de choses et que cette action se retourne contre nous, nous affecte alors que ce n'était pas envisagé.

Voici une façon d'utiliser *effet boomerang* dans la phrase proposée en exemple :

> Imposer cette réforme des mathématiques aura un effet boomerang sur notre travail de professeur.

Comment: Merci. J'ai modifié la phrase:-)!

Comment: Il faudrait écrire *la réforme aura un effet boomerang **sur** notre travail* mais ce n'est pas très clair car une réforme n'est pas une action. On ne sait pas trop qui parle non plus, est-ce que ce sont les personnes à l'origine de cette réforme ?

Comment: Merci encore. Oui ce sont des personnes. Je veux dire que pour maintenant la reforme peut faire la vie des profs et des élèves plus facile (moins de cours, matière réduite) mais elle va se retourner contre nous.

Comment: Les réformes ne sont en général pas conçues et décidées par "les professeurs" mais plutôt par un ministère ou une autre hiérarchie. De plus, on parle plus d'un effet boomerang quand on a imposé quelque chose de désagréable à quelqu'un alors que dans ce que tu décris, les nouvelles règles s'appliquent déjà aux professeurs comme aux élèves et ne sont pas des contraintes.

Comment: Je pense que mon exemple n'est pas bien:-)! Si tu veux je peux l'effacer et laisser la question demandant un exemple d'emploi courant.

Comment: Tu peux la laisser. C'est un bon contre-exemple d'utilisation ;-)